# Absolute function

Tags: scala, bigdecimal, absolute

In my program I am using Bigdecimal to truncate numbers and storing them in a variable. Eg. 123.456789 is getting displayed as 123.45.Further I am trying to find the absolute of the numbers.The problem arises here i.e - 123.45 should appear as 123.45 but it's appearing as 123.4589Egh.Can someone please help as to how can I find absolute of numbers.

```
var diff1=BigDecimal(diff).setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
var bigdec=abs(diff1)
```

Try taking inputs for 10-15 numbers in an array (in diff variable)

Comment: Try posting code that reliably reproduces the problem you're trying to describe.

Answer (score 3):

Uhm, I'm not sure what your problem is, but for me this works fine:

```
val diff = -123.456789
var diff1 = BigDecimal(diff).setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.DOWN).toDouble
var bigdec = Math.abs(diff1)
println(bigdec) // 123.45
```

Note that if you want 123.45 instead of 123.46 you have to change your rounding mode.

Answer (score 1):

Taking in an array doesn't change anything, although you need to make a def and map over the array now when rounding - as you cannot call the BigDecimal apply function on an Array:

```
// generates an Array of 20 elements with random doubles from 0 to 200
val diff = Array.fill(20)(math.random).map(_ * 200)
  .map { num => // using this map function to make some negatives
    if (num < 100) num * -1
    else num
  }

def round(double: Double) = BigDecimal(double)
  .setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
  .toDouble

var absolute = diff.map(num => Math.abs(round(num)))
```

Does the above code reflect what you are doing? If so, for `var absolute` I am getting an `Array[Double]` with positive numbers and only 2 decimal places.